# Can I use medical injection water to fill lead acid battery?

Tags: batteries, lead-acid, water

Can I use sodium chloride injection ip (0.9% W/V) instead of distilled water to fill a lead acid battery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because it contains conductive ions of sodium and chloride.

The water you put into batteries is deionized/distilled/purified water to especially remove any conductive ions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt. And Can we use water that is made by boiling and capturing the vaporized water?

Comment: And produce chlorine gas! Very toxic.

Comment: @Revanth. Sounds like distilled water you are describing.

Comment: @Kartman. Yes, I am saying that cooling the water vapour that came from boiling water. Can i use that?

Comment: *cooling the water vapour that came from boiling water* That is what we call "distilled water". Does the answer say you can use distilled water? Realize that in most DIY stores, they sell deionized water which is cheap and will do the job. Distilling your own water sounds like too much trouble.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie. Thank you for replying. The distilled water is not available in my area and no one selling them. I'm just trying to figure out the methods to make it and use it in lead acid battery. Anyways, I will soon or later buy the distilled water.

Comment: Update: I made distilled water that is 5 ppm. Normally TDS of distilled water is 0.5 ppm. Is it still safe to use ?

Comment: 5ppm sounds good enough for a battery, but higher purity is better,

Comment: Home made distilled water is fine. Double distilling purifies it BUT should not be needed.

Comment: @Revanth Are you sure nobody is selling it? I can get it in gas station (to mix with antifreeze) or in supermarkets (to use in irons).

Comment: @Rokta Thankyou for replying, I live in India and in rural area. So no one sells them here.

Comment: @Russell McMahon. I already filled 3/4th of my battery with my home made distilled water with tds of 5ppm (because when I searched on google, below 5ppm is good enough for lead acid battery) and Its working fine. And the lead acid battery is used for my computer UPS for stopping my pc from sudden powerlosses...

Comment: @Jasen. Thats why I used it in my lead acid battery :)

Comment: Rain water (which may not always be available)  is usually good - more so away from industrial  areas. How are you measuring TDs - or is that an estimate? || For interest, where are you located?. || I've visited Chennai, Pune, Delhi, Agra, Mumbai.

Comment: @Russell McMahon. I live in Andhra Pradesh near Kadapa, and I have a TDS meter which is cheap and I bought it from Amazon which works fine. Usually Rain water is good idea but it isn't raining now. But I used hone made distilled water which is working surprisingly well with my Lead acid battery in UPS. I needed to fix that quickly because, sudden powerlosses are common which make HDD and SSD in my pc worse and as we have to work with pc in my small business.